# Row number partion by in sql

Tags: sql

Here is my table

[image]

`Guid` is unique.  One `guid` associate with one user only.  There will not be same `guid` for diff user.  Here I want all col like `Userid, guid, status, Errorcode and Retry`.  I want to fetch all record from table where retry is max for that `guid`.

Like this

[image]

Retry can be 0 or 1 or 2 for that `guid`.

My query :

```
SELECT
  Userid,
  Guid,
  Status,
  ErrorCode,
  Retry,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Userid, Guid ORDER BY Retry) AS Row_Number
FROM UserInfo
```

If I put `Row_Number=1` will get only first for that `guid`.
I want to choose max retry record for that `guid`.

Comment: _"Guid is unique"_ alright, but how does user1 have guid 2222 and guid 3333? The GUID doesn't identify the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` in fact should work here, but you need to use `ORDER BY Retry DESC` in the call:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, Guid ORDER BY Retry DESC) rn
    FROM UserInfo
)

SELECT userid, Guid, Status, ErrorCode, Retry
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

If you are using SQL Server, then we can actually write your query without even using a formal subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES userid, Guid, Status, ErrorCode, Retry
FROM UserInfo
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, Guid ORDER BY Retry DESC);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your query, no need to user row_number, `MAX()` will solve this.

```
select t2.userid, t2.Guid, t2.Status, t2.ErrorCode, t1.maxRet from 
UserInfo
inner Join
(select 
 max(Retry) AS maxRet, userid, Guid
from UserInfo
Group by userid, Guid) as t1
on t1.Guid = t2.Guid and t1.userid = t2.userid
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ORDER BY Retry desc`

```
select * from
(
select userid,Guid,Status,ErrorCode,Retry,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition by userid,Guid ORDER BY Retry desc) AS Row_Number
from UserInfo
)A where Row_Number=1
```